# What is the significance of Bruce Lee tasting his own blood in Enter the Dragon?

Tags: enter-the-dragon

In the movie *Enter the Dragon*, the main antagonist of the film scratches Bruce Lee several times with a claw-like hand. In one of the last attempts with the claw, Bruce Lee rubs some of the blood from his body and gently touches it to his tongue, then continues to fight.

This scene is also parodied in *That 70's Show* where Fez is having a dream scenario where he is fighting ninjas, so it must be a pivitol moment in the film?

Answer (score 4):

**I'm not sure *significance* is the right word.**

Essentially, it's an acknowledgement that the opponent has scored a "hit" and the fight is about to get **serious**.

The tasting of the blood is Lee basically saying...

> "OK, you tagged me, now it's gonna get **real**."

It happens in several of Lee's movies.

Comment: I thought that at first but he's "tagged" several times before "it gets real"..he's scratches at least 2 or 3 times before the belly hit, and gets hit afterwards too. I guess it's just theatrics

Comment: There is no disagreement here. What @Paulie_D describes _is_ theatrics. You've both nailed it. Truth is convergent.